# How to properly refresh slick carousel in Angular with ng-repeat generated slides

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slick.js

I have a rather complex carousel that is generated from a template with ng-repeat, using data supplied by an ajax call. The data gets periodically updated every minute. This works fine for a while, but eventually the browser slows to a crawl and stops responding to user input.

I have created a plunker demonstrating the issue [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fj0fwpFYnDrst5UzqYUc). The refresh is triggered like so:

```
var watch = $scope.$watch('items', function () {
    // just a deep copy in place of more complex processing in the real world scenario
    $scope.processeditems = angular.copy($scope.items);

    // refresh carousel
    if (slick.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        console.log('unslicking');

        slick.slick('unslick');
        slick.slick(options);
    }
});
```

Obviously the timescale in this example is exaggerated greatly (on the other hand the presentation is dead simple compared to my real world scenario with a couple of layers of directives on each item). The refresh cycle starts affecting performance after a few hundred iterations - try scrolling the code in the editor panel to observe the steady deterioration. This is a lot more pronounced in my original code - it only takes 10-20 refreshes to become noticable there.

The problem manifests itself only with unslick/slick in place. There also appears to be no problem if I leave out the $watch and wire up the ng-repeat directly to the original $scope variable. Unfortunately I have to do some processing in the real world scenario so I cannot use this approach without some heavy modification. Which is always an option, but I would like to figure out what I'm doing wrong here regardless. Any ideas?